# function for limiting number of selected checkboxes not working (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

guys, I'm stuck at a limited number of selected checkboxes. Basically, if the user selects more than 1 checkbox he will get a warning but when I test it nothing happens. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
<div id="checkboxgroup">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="1" /><label for="1">Izdelki zabavne elektronike</label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="2" /><label for="2">Svetlobni efekti v ritmu glasbe (light show) </label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="3" /><label for="3">Barvno mešanje svetlobe </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="4" /><label for="4">Uporabna elektronika </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="5" /><label for="5">Izdelava robota Otto </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="6" /><label for="6">CADCAM in CNC </label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="7" /><label for="7">Robotika </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="8" /><label for="8">Varjenje </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="9" /><label for="9">Programiranje v GDScript </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="10" /><label for="10">Programiranje v C# </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="11" /><label for="11">Avtomatika </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="12" /><label for="12">Od 3D animacije do izdelka na CNC stroju (Strokovna
        gimnazija) </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="13" /><label for="13">Zabavno računalniško programiranje (Strokovna
        gimnazija) </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="14" /><label for="14">Detektor laži (Strokovna gimnazija) </label> <br>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    onlyOneCheckBox()
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onlyOneCheckBox() {
        var checkboxgroup = document.getElementById('checkboxgroup').getElementsByTagName("input");
        var limit = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxgroup.length; i++) {
            checkboxgroup[i].onclick = function () {
                var checkedcount = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < checkboxgroup.length; i++) {
                    checkedcount += (checkboxgroup[i].checked) ? 1 : 0;
                }
                if (checkedcount > limit) {
                    console.log("You can select maximum of " + limit + " checkbox.");
                    alert("You can select maximum of " + limit + " checkbox.");
                    this.checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand—it seems like you only call the function once, on the initial render.

Comment: If you want only one selection, using radio buttons would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not required to create a function to record the click action.

```
<div id="checkboxgroup">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="1" /><label for="1">Izdelki zabavne elektronike</label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="2" /><label for="2">Svetlobni efekti v ritmu glasbe (light show) </label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="3" /><label for="3">Barvno mešanje svetlobe </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="4" /><label for="4">Uporabna elektronika </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="5" /><label for="5">Izdelava robota Otto </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="6" /><label for="6">CADCAM in CNC </label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="7" /><label for="7">Robotika </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="8" /><label for="8">Varjenje </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="9" /><label for="9">Programiranje v GDScript </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="10" /><label for="10">Programiranje v C# </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="11" /><label for="11">Avtomatika </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="12" /><label for="12">Od 3D animacije do izdelka na CNC stroju (Strokovna
        gimnazija) </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="13" /><label for="13">Zabavno računalniško programiranje (Strokovna
        gimnazija) </label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="14" /><label for="14">Detektor laži (Strokovna gimnazija) </label> <br>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // function onlyOneCheckBox() {
        var checkboxgroup = document.getElementById('checkboxgroup').getElementsByTagName("input");
        var limit = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxgroup.length; i++) {
            checkboxgroup[i].onclick = function () {
                var checkedcount = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < checkboxgroup.length; i++) {
                    checkedcount += (checkboxgroup[i].checked) ? 1 : 0;
                }
                if (checkedcount > limit) {
                    console.log("You can select maximum of " + limit + " checkbox.");
                    alert("You can select maximum of " + limit + " checkbox.");
                    this.checked = false;
                }
            }
        }

</script>
```